# Angular 5 : How to import jQuery in Jest test?

Tags: jquery, angular, mocking, angular5, jestjs

I have an angular component that use a CalendarService.
When the component is init, I call a "calendarService.init()" method.

This CalendarService set the configuration of a semantic-ui-calendar (base on jQuery), with a code like "$(myElement).calendar(settings);".

When I test my component with Jest, the initialization of the component has an error : "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

How can i fix it ?

search.component.spec.ts :

```
describe('SearchComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let element: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/search' },
        CalendarService
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);

    let calendarService = TestBed.get(CalendarService);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.debugElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
});
```

search.component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'afo-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.less']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calendarService.init();
  }

}
```

calendar.service.ts :

```
@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {

  constructor() {
  }

  init() {
    $('.ui.calendar.field').calendar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution :

I need to add the followings lines in my setupJest.ts :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
Object.defineProperty(window, '$', {value: $});
Object.defineProperty(global, '$', {value: $});
Object.defineProperty(global, 'jQuery', {value: $});
```

At the begining, I tried this solution :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

But global.xxx and window.xxx were unknown.

See :

https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular#allow-vendor-libraries-like-jquery-etc

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/708

Comment: OMFG you are amazing!!  If I could I'd plaster this answer acros the whole site…none of the much higher scored answers worked.  BTW in case anyone else has an issue I found that Object.defineProperty(window, '$', {value: $}); caused problems and I could skip it.

Comment: But I found I needed import $ from 'jquery'; rather than import * as $ from 'jquery'; and in some cases I needed to be using the jsdom enviornment.

Comment: For more recent setups (e.g Angular 11/Jest/NX combo), you can add the above solution to test-setup.ts

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported jquery?

```
declare var jquery:any;   // not required
declare var $ :any;   // not required
```

Comment: Yes, but I finally found the solution.
See my next answer ;)